# GUI Wallet - Tails Setup

Tags: monero-wallet-gui

I'm trying to set up the pruned GUI wallet following the instructions (and code) here: https://www.reddit.com/r/Monero/comments/h8pbc2/guide_setting_up_a_monero_full_node_on_tails/

I downloaded Tails this week, so my version should be up to date, but whenever I run the code it gets to approximately 50% and essentially stalls out. I get the following errors over and over again. I'm not very experienced, so please help me out here!

````
2021-02-02 19:41:23.652 I SYNCHRONIZATION started
2021-02-02 19:42:44.939 W There were 0 blocks in the last 90 minutes, there might be large hash rate changes, or we might be partitioned, cut off from the Monero network or under attack, or your computer's time is off. Or it could be just sheer bad luck.
2021-02-02 19:42:55.887 I [78.46.68.58:18080 OUT] Sync data returned a new top block candidate: 1138064 -> 2288202 [Your node is 1150138 blocks (4.4 years) behind] 
2021-02-02 19:42:55.887 I SYNCHRONIZATION started
2021-02-02 19:44:14.949 W There were 0 blocks in the last 90 minutes, there might be large hash rate changes, or we might be partitioned, cut off from the Monero network or under attack, or your computer's time is off. Or it could be just sheer bad luck.
1612295100 ERROR torsocks[12923]: General SOCKS server failure (in socks5_recv_connect_reply() at socks5.c:527)
2021-02-02 19:45:44.961 W There were 0 blocks in the last 90 minutes, there might be large hash rate changes, or we might be partitioned, cut off from the Monero network or under attack, or your computer's time is off. Or it could be just sheer bad luck.```
````

Answer (score 2):

Syncing over tor is hard, I had the same issues, restarted many times, but you will get through in the end.

Comment: I’d thought so, but it’s been days since I’ve made any progress. Even with restarts.

Comment: These are not the droids I was looking for